# How to Detect Android Browsers but Not Android App (WebView)?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, webview

I have created an Android app for my website `example.com` using WebView. Now I want my users to browse my website only from the app so I want to show a message on the footer as **Quora** does for the Android users browsing from browsers. See image below for reference:

[image]

Now the problem is I am using webView of `example.com` in the app and I want to display the message on 'example.com` itself so whatever codes I use to show the message also gets displayed in webView. Is there any way to detect or differentiate between android browsers and android webView apps?

Note: I want to show the message on the website and not in the app. So provide codes in PHP, HTML or javascript and not Java.

Comment: you can do it by deep linking your android app

Answer (score 1):

Gives same o/p for both webView as well as browser.

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"];
$url1 = "com.chatadda.free";
$url2 = "com.chatadda.android";
$url3 = "com.chatadda.android.pro";
$url4 = "com.chatadda.android.premium";
if($url != $url1 || $url != $url2 || $url != $url3 || $url != $url4) {
echo "Not on App";
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"];
}
else {
echo "On App";
}
?>
```

Comment: Didn't you get the problem here?
It's not about detecting if the device is android or not. It's detecting if it's android browser or webView app.

Comment: No It is checking if it is a android device or not

Comment: No. I want to check if it's android web browser or android app's webView intent.

Comment: Oh sry, And if you try `stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false`

Comment: You still don't get the problem.

Comment: I think it is only possibe if you know the name of your app(package name)

Comment: it's com.chatadda.free

Comment: if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "com.chatadda.free")
    echo 'var isAndroidApp=true;
else
    echo 'var isAndroidApp=false;

Comment: Update it in the answer so if it works I can accept the answer.

Comment: No it did not work. It gives the same o/p `Not on App` for both browsers as well as android WebView App.

Comment: It seems that it only didn't work for you because there are some querstions like that which are solved with this solution

Comment: @Reit I don't understand. What did you say? Why didn't it work? If it's wrong code please update it with the right code. Also checkout this app: I want the website http://chatadda.com to redirect to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chatadda.free&hl=en for android browsers but I don't want it to redirect for the users viewing the site from the app mentioned in the above link. Install the app and visit the site. You'll understand the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting your custom header key&value or override user-agent when webView load page?

For example,

```
String userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() + "/" + YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME;
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

or

```
Map<String,String> extraHeader = new HashMap<String, String>();
extraHeader.put("isApp", "true");
webView.loadUrl(url, extraHeader);
```

Comment: I want the codes for my server (PHP) not in the app.

Comment: Is checking $_SERVER['YOUR_CUSTOM_KEY'] not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "YOUR_CUSTOM_KEY"?